# Choosing indexes and primary keys for performance

Tags: sql, database, performance, postgresql, database-design

I am new to database design and I am having a lot of trouble on designing a PostgreSQL database for a combat game.

On this game, players will fight between them, gaining resources to buy better weapons and armors. Combats will be recorded for future review and the number of combats is expected to grow rapidly, as, for example, 1k players fighting 1k rounds will produce 500k records.

Game interactivity is reduced to spend points to upgrade the fighter equipment and habilities. Combats are resolved by the machine.

Details:

- A specific type of weapon or armor can only be possesed once by each fighter.
- Fighters will almost exclusively searched by `id`.
- I will often need to search what pieces of equipment (weapons and/or armor) are possesed by a specific fighter, but I do not expect to search which fighters posseses a specific type of weapon.
- Combats will be often searched by `winner` or `loser`.
- Two given `fighters` can fight multiple times on different dates, so the tuple `winner`-`loser` is not unique on table `combats`
- `fighters` table contains a lot of columns that will be often retrieved all at the same time (I create two objects of class "Fighter" with all the related information anytime a combat begins)

This is my current design:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS weapons (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    *** Game stuff ***
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS armors (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    *** Game stuff ***
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fighters (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    preferred_weapon INT references weapons(id),
    preferred_armor INT references armors(id),
    *** Game stuff ***
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS combats (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    winner INT references fighters(id),
    loser  INT references fighters(id),
    *** Game stuff ***
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fighters_weapons (
    fighter INT NOT NULL references fighters(id),
    weapon INT NOT NULL references weapons(id),
    PRIMARY KEY(fighter, weapon)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fighters_armors (
    fighter INT NOT NULL references fighters(id),
    armor INT NOT NULL references armors(id),
    PRIMARY KEY(fighter, armor)
);
```

My questions are:

1. Do you think my design is well suited?
2. I have seen a lot of example databases containing an `id` column as primary key on every table. Is there any reason for that? Should I do that instead of the multiple column primary keys I am using on `fighters_weapons` and `fighters_armors`?
3. PostgreSQL creates indexes automatically for each primary key, but there are several tables which I do not expect to search by it (i. e. `combats`). Should I remove the index for performance? PostgreSQL complains about an existing constraint.
4. As I will search `fighters_weapons` and `fighters_armors` by `fighter`, as well as `combats` by `winner` and `loser`, do you think I should create indexes for all of this columns on these tables?
5. Any performance improvement advice? The most used operations will be: insert and query fighters, query equipment for a given fighter and insert combats.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Minor nitpick: "to loose" is the opposite of "to tighten", "to lose"  is the opposite of "to find" (so your column should be called `loser`

Comment: Technically `combats` doesn't need it's own primary key, it can use the `winner`/`loser` tuple like several of the other association tables use.  What type of game is this - real-time, turn-based, etc?  If you want us to give you more help, you're going to need to give us the full layout of the various tables (especially `fighters`).  Hmm.. Most recommendations I've seen tend to say to name tables in the singular (eg `fighter`).  You're going to want indices on every primary key, whatever it is.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: Thanks for your answer :) I have edited the initial question with the following:

Comment: Sorry, this is the rest of the response:    The game is not real-time, nor turn-based, as interactivity is reduced to spend points to upgrade the fighter equipment and habilities. Combats are resolved by the machine.  I think `winner`/`loser` tuples can not be primary keys because the fighters can combat several times between them (enemy assignment is nearly random).  Data not provided for the tables as `fighters` or `weapons` is just `name`, `strength`, `damage` and numeric fields like that which I think are irrelevant for the database design

Comment: Somewhat off-topic, but in case you were considering ... avoid hosting on EC2 if you need good performance out of Pg, I've generally seen very poor performance from Pg on EC2. Get a real physical host, or at least a cloud host with really good storage.

Comment: The basic key structure looks reasonable. There is a small problem with fights that not have been decided yet: since your fights table only has {winner,loser} as FKs to fighter, for an undecided ungoing fight there will no way to relate the two fighters to the combat. ALSO, I would advise to add additional unique indexes on the junction tables, eg `unique index xxx on fighter_weapon (weapon, fighter)` (and the same for fighter_armor) Note: the {preferred_weapon, preferred_armor} allow for only one preference.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: "to loose" could also mean to release an arrow, so it sort of fits, depending on what weapons are involved. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To address your explicit questions:

2) It can be preferable to use a "natural" value as a primary key, i.e. not a serial id, if one exists. In cases where you are unlikely to use a serial id as an identifier, I would say it's slight better not to add it.

3) Unless you intend to insert many rows very quickly into the combats table, it probably won't hurt you too much to have the index on the id column.

4) Creating an index on {fighter} is not necessary if the index {fighter, weapon} exists, and similarly creating an index on {fighter} is not necessary if the index {fighter, armor} exists. In general, you don't benefit from creating an index that is the prefix of another multi-column index. Separately, creating {winner} and {loser} indexes on combats seems like a good idea given the access pattern you've described.

5) Beyond table design, there are a few database tuning parameters that you might want to set if you've installed the database yourself. If an experienced database administrator has set up the database, he/she has probably already done this for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot; that was very useful. Regarding 5), I manage the database myself, but have not experience at all on doing that. Will try to search for information regarding PSQL tunning.